# Angular Material with Lazy Loading Module

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-routing, angular-lazyloading

i already found that which looks similar but does not help me. [Lazy loading Angular modules with latest Angular material design gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983564/lazy-loading-angular-modules-with-latest-angular-material-design-gives-error)

My problem is, that i have lazy loading modules. app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home-routing.module').then(m => m.HomeRoutingModule)},
  {path: '**', loadChildren: () => import('./error/error-routing.module').then(m => m.ErrorRoutingModule)}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

And home routing module looks like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(
    [
      {path: '', component: NavigationComponent},
    ]
  )]
})
export class HomeRoutingModule {
}
```

The navigation component is just the generated material schema for the sidenav.
https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics#navigation-schematic

But as a result i get:

> Error: src/app/home/navigation/navigation.component.html:1:1 - error
> NG8001: 'mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message.

Moving the sidenav code, to app.component.html everything works fine.

My home module is like

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NavigationComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

Have no glue what i am doing wrong?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import lazy loading Module, you need to import the main module, that contain the component declarations, and the needed module for these component:

In your app-routing.module

```
//home.module and HomeModule, instead of HomeRoutingModule
{path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => 
m.HomeModule)}
```

In your homeRoutingModule, you need to export RouterModule:

```
 @NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forChild(
   [
     {path: '', component: NavigationComponent},
   ]
 )],
 exports: [RouterModule]
 })
```

Finally, in your HomeModule, you import your HomeRoutingModule:

```
imports: [
 ...
 HomeRoutingModule,
 ....

]
```